Trying to understand the IBM Models for machine translation
I came across some old literature on machine translation, specifically IBM Model 1 here: https://aclanthology.org/J93-2003.pdf. In it, the author makes the makes the statement : "If we replace $\lambda_e$ by $\lambda_e$ $P(\bf{f}|\bf{e})$" (page number 270 - 271, equations 11, 12, 13 is the relevant context). I understand if we multiple and divide by $P(\bf{f} | \bf{e})$ but how can we just "replace" something like that?
